# WritePad Handwriting Recognition SDK for WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, handwriting-recognition

I have a problem with WritePad Handwriting Recognition SDK for WP8 I installed the sdk for windows `WritePadSDK_Windows_42`, and I add the library for pthread, and it works with Win8 but not WP8 There is no error, only this line

`if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`
[image]

> Message = "Unable to load DLL 'WinRT_CPPLayer.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

`WinRT_CPPLayer.dll` it is a library in C++ for `WritePadSDK`for windows, and I can't add this library to the project.
How can I add C++ library to WP8 project???